# What is the lowest and highest value you can use for numeric values in an ARFF file?

Tags: types, limit, weka, numeric, limits

I'm using Weka and would like to know what are the limits for the numeric attribute type. This is for the ARFF file format.

For instance, can you use negative numbers? What is the highest number you can use? I need to know this before I can start dealing with very large numbers. Unfortunately, my textbook on Weka does not list the limits of the numeric type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numeric attribute can be either real or integer values. In relation to to maximum value, I found this in the Weka developer documentation.

> ```
> @attribute temperature real
> @attribute humidity real
> ```
>
> These lines define two numeric attributes. Instead of real, integer or
>   numeric can also be used. While double floating point values are
>   stored internally, only seven decimal digits are usually processed.

So the JVM will view any values loaded as double floating point values, but if you have more than seven decimal places the number may be truncated.